# Which was the best way to store the data that was coming from excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i have written a code to read the excel data from an excel, but i don't know which was the best way to store the data my data in excel is as follows

```
               2000-01       2001-02     2002-03    2003-04   2004-05

Some text        65%           52%          51.3%      *        6.1%
Some text        65%           52%          51.3%      *        6.1%
Some text        65%           52%          51.3%      *        6.1%
Some text        65%           52%          51.3%      *        6.1%
Some text        65%           52%          51.3%      *        6.1%
```

The data seems to be as this in my excel file i know how to retrieve the data but i was looking for the best method to store the data can any one help me

AT present i am storing data in to `List<string>` as follows

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A11", "G21");
System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value2;
List<string> newList = AnyListToStrList(myvalues);
```

But i am not sure that it was the right method so i am looking for the better one..

Comment: what do you want to do with the data when and after you store it ? what have tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: where do you want to save the data in a file or in a DataBase?

Comment: I would like to save the data to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 tables:

```
main (
id int,
description varchar(255)
)

period
(
main_id int (fk main(id))
period int,
period_length int, --in months or years, whatever is more appropriate
period_value float
)
```

Comment: As per the first table i would like to give a look up for my text right?

Comment: @Ramakrishna: The first table is meant to hold a unique id (id) and a `description` which should map to the `Some Text` sample text you put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it in a database and actually show an excel document when you retrieve the data, I would suggest storing the file itself, it just reduces the hassle that comes with Excel Automation, such as creating the excel file.

Comment: I don't need the whole excel file as per my requirement i would like to store the data that was required from excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to save from excel to database I would use a data structure as close as possible to the final da tables so to be able to detect issues the earliest. For example you could use a datatable with same column names and types as it is in your database.